# ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found. ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, ubuntu-16.04

i am using python wand.Image to import image in following way.

```
from wand.image import Image
```

on my local machine i have imagemagick installed and it is working fine. But on my production server when i am trying to run this code i am getting following error. [image]

i have tried installing imagemagick on production server as well and upon running `apt -qq list imagemagick` i am getting following output.

> imagemagick/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13
>   amd64 [installed]

i have installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 on the production server.

Comment: did you try installing the following: `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: yes tried that as well but no luck

Comment: are you using docker in production?

Comment: yes i have docker container in production.

Comment: Are you using Python's docker or ubuntu's docker in production

Comment: i am using python docker

Comment: That is the issue, I had the same issue. And we changed it to ubuntu docker, then it worked.